# Ruby on Rails X expected, got string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that basically shows checkboxes using collection_check_boxes... I also have what I believe to be the correct thing inside of the controller to expect the form, but I'm getting a weird error that I haven't seen all day long

Here's my _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @report, :html => {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <% if @report.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@report.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this report from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @report.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :phases, class: "col-sm-3 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :phases, Phase.all, :id, :name %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <%= f.submit nil, class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The controller has this for the params:

```
params.require(:report).permit(:phases => [])
```

Here's the error I get when submitting the form:

> Phase(#70354525541300) expected, got String(#5990260)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I got it fixed by removing the model associations, but are associations actually needed? I just simply want a form with checkboxes and have them auto-check (when i edit or view the form) based on what's the database. Idk why this seems so difficult.

Answer (score 2):

> are associations actually needed?

lol.

---

You got your error because you passed a `string` when Rails was expecting an `object`. Use the following:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :phase_ids, Phase.all, :id, :name %>

params.require(:report).permit(phase_ids: [])
```

If you want to populate a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association (which is what I presume you to have), you'll want to use the [`collection_singular_ids`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) attribute. This accepts the keys you're sending from your HTML form (explained below):

--

What you did was the equivalent of this:

```
#app/models/report.rb
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :phases
end

params: {
    report : { 
       "phases": ["3", "5", "6"]
    }
}
```

The "phases" association is meant to be populated with an [`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) (IE ActiveRecord will pull the associated objects from the `phases` database).

When you use the `collection_check_boxes`, you're *only* sending the primary keys of the objects you wish to pick. See for yourself in your params; thus, when you permit the param directly through your controller, Rails is going to have an issue where it needs the `Phase` objects.

The solution is to populate the `phase_ids` attribute as described in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:
      `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :phases, Phase.all, :id, :name %>`

Try changing :phases to :phase_ids:
      `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :phase_ids, Phase.all, :id, :name %>`

And on the controller, change: 
`params.require(:report).permit(:phases => [])`
to:
`params.require(:report).permit(:phase_ids => [])`

I didn't do a test of this, but to my knowledge this ought to work.

Comment: Getting this error when changing phases to phase_ids: undefined method `phase_ids' for #<Report:0x007f262d071250>